# Could a skyhook be used to change a satelites orbit from polar to equitorial?

Tags: physics, engineering

Could this work if the skyhook also had ion engines to maintain its orbit or would the cable just snap?

Comment: You want mechanical systems between bodies with $\approx$ 8 km/s?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Could a skyhook be used to change a satelites orbit from polar to equitorial?

No

There are several [posts about skyhooks](https://space.stackexchange.com/search?q=skyhook+) They are used to to move from one specific place (Earth) to another specific place (special orbit) and back.

To do what you ask; the [skyhook](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skyhook_(structure)) would need to be oriented between the current orbit and proposed orbit of the satellite.  There is no practical reason to do that.  The amount of fuel and resource to accomplish the goal, would be significantly greater then launching a new satellite, or sending a one time mission to reorientation the existing satellite.